# How to recover work lost due to an Ubuntu One sync error?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I had a document that was synchronised by Ubuntu One. I edited it yesterday, but when I opened it today it was a month old version.

What can I do to recover my work?

Comment: This is a complaint/support request rather than a question.

Comment: It is clearly a question. Sure, it is a support request too, but it still is a question, and having a good answer here can help not only the OP, but future people who experiment this problem. Unluckily I don't know nothing about Ubuntu One.

Comment: Upppssss... yes it was a complaint, it's because of dv3500 edit that it's a question now. Sometime I miss to be able to award rep for editing. Great work ;).

Answer (score 4):

Occasionally when you edit a document that is being synchronized by Ubuntu One the program that does the synchronization doesn't realize what's going on (that you're editing a file), and sees the new versions on the server as conflicting with the changes you have made locally. This is a bug, and I believe it is fixed (the person who would know is not working today, and I can't find the bug; I'll edit this answer when I get the info), but in any case, none of your work should be lost: when the situation arises, your document should be simply renamed. You should find that there are a bunch of files that start with the same name as your document, and have a `.u1conflict` and a number added at the end. The largest number would correspond to the last version of your file.

If this is not the case, and you can't find any `.u1conflict` files, please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug?field.title=Edits+lost+and+no+.u1conflict+files+found). Please set the Importance to Critical, assign it to me, and add a comment to this answer with the bug number, just to make sure.

Thank you.